# Generic for FnOnce that returns a future with a lifetime

Tags: rust, async-await

I have a struct that needs a callback that returns a future whose output has a lifetime:

```rust
struct Foo;
struct Bar;

struct Baz<F>
where F: for<'a> FnOnce(&'a Foo) -> impl std::future::Future<Output=&'a Bar> // ?
{
    cb: F
}
```

That doesn't compile, with a syntax error since `impl` can't appear in trait bounds:

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0562]: `impl Trait` not allowed outside of function and inherent method return types
 --> src/lib.rs:6:37
  |
6 | where F: for<'a> FnOnce(&'a Foo) -> impl std::future::Future<Output=&'a Bar>,
  |                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

This doesn't compile either:

```rust
struct Foo;
struct Bar;

struct Baz<O, F>
where
    O: for<'a> std::future::Future<Output=&'a Bar>,
    F: for<'b> FnOnce(&'b Foo) -> O,
{
    cb: F
}
```

Complaining that `'a` isn't recognized (and the lifetimes `'a` and `'b` would be unrelated):

```
   Compiling playground v0.0.1 (/playground)
error[E0582]: binding for associated type `Output` references lifetime `'a`, which does not appear in the trait input types
 --> src/lib.rs:7:36
  |
7 |     O: for<'a> std::future::Future<Output=&'a Bar>,
  |                                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

error: aborting due to previous error
```

Is there a way to specify this relationship?

Comment: Can you include the specific errors for "didn't compile"? Try not to paraphrase, you might miss something important. Just include the exact error text.

Comment: @tadman I can, but it's not going to help. Neither of the approaches are correct.

Comment: The specific errors are a lot more informative, and also if someone else with this exact problem has the same error, now they can find this.

Answer (score 5):

It's a bit ugly, but this is the best way I could find (using `struct Foo(Bar)` for demonstration):

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=392adc979bad1a67a4e5042506cbbfbc)

```rust
use std::future::Future;

struct Bar;
struct Foo(Bar);

trait FooClosure<'a> {
    type Fut: Future<Output = &'a Bar>;

    fn call(self, foo: &'a Foo) -> Self::Fut;
}

impl<'a, Fut: Future<Output = &'a Bar>, C: FnOnce(&'a Foo) -> Fut> FooClosure<'a> for C {
    type Fut = Fut;

    fn call(self, foo: &'a Foo) -> Fut {
        self(foo)
    }
}

struct Baz<F: for<'a> FooClosure<'a>>(F);

fn main() {
    let closure: Box<dyn for<'a> FnOnce(&'a Foo) -> futures::future::Ready<&'a Bar>> =
        Box::new(|foo| futures::future::ready(&foo.0));
    let baz = Baz(closure);
}
```

I couldn't get the compiler to infer the types properly, so I had to wrap the closure as boxed trait object. Theoretically this shouldn't be necessary, and there might be a way to avoid this but I couldn't figure it out.

Note: I think there are plans to make your original code work without needing this trait black magic.

Comment: One way to help the compiler with type inference without requiring the annoying boxing is to introduce yet another helper function: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=3016d1b6ed02c6ec89ee3d4a8c2e058e

Answer (score -1):

A straightforward way to do this is to parameterize the struct `Baz` itself with the lifetime parameter:

```
struct Baz<'a, O: Future<Output=&'a Bar>, F: FnOnce(&'a Foo) -> O> {
    cb: F,
    phantom: PhantomData<&'a O>,
}
```

The [`PhantomData`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/marker/struct.PhantomData.html) instance is required to "use" the lifetime parameter `'a` and the output type parameter `O`. You can think of `O` and `'a` as components of the closure type `F` -- they will always be implicitly inferred from the lifetime and return type used by `F`.

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=51059954d91d2ad6a7d8f1407a4bdfb6)

Comment: This isn't exactly the same thing OP is asking for, since it forces you to make one choice of `'a` work everywhere for the same instance of `Baz`, instead of having each `'a` be chosen at the call site of the closure.