# Calling a generic async function with a (mutably) borrowed argument

Tags: rust, async-await

Minimal example of my issue.

```
use std::future::Future;

async fn call_changer<'a, F, Fut>(changer: F)
where
    F: FnOnce(&'a mut i32) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = ()> + 'a,
{
    let mut i = 0;
    changer(&mut i).await; // error 1
    dbg!(i); // error 2
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    call_changer(|i| async move {
        *i = 100;
    })
    .await;
}
```

This leads to two related errors, see [rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c30b4e285eb7fed1c038a69a5e4a3cdf) for detailed output:

1. The borrow not living long enough because `i` gets dropped at the end of `call_changer`'s body.
2. `i` cannot be used after the await because it is still being mutably borrowed.

I am a bit surprised by both, I understand why the `Future` return of `F` needs to have the same lifetime (`'a`) as its borrow ([relevant async book section](https://rust-lang.github.io/async-book/03_async_await/01_chapter.html)). However, according to that same reference, the borrow should be over as soon as I call the await on `changer`'s result, which clearly does not happen or I would not have those errors. Reworking this example to something like the book where the `changer` function is not passed in as a parameter but just called directly works as expected.

What is going on here, and can I do anything about it? Replacing `&mut` with an `Rc<RefCell<_>>` construct works as expected, but if possible I'd like to avoid that.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

When you specify `'a` as a generic parameter, you mean "I permit the caller to choose any lifetime it wants". The caller may as well choose `'static`, for example. Then you promise to pass `&'a mut i32`, that is, `&'static mut i32`. But `i` does not live for `'static`! That's the reason for the first error.

The second error is because you're promising you're borrowing `i` mutably for `'a`. But again, `'a` may as well cover the entire function, even after you discarded the result! The caller may choose `'static`, for example, then store the reference in a global variable. If you use `i` after, you use it while it is mutably borrowed. BOOM!

What you want is *not* to let the caller choose the lifetime, but instead to say "I'm passing you a reference with *some* lifetime `'a`, and I want you to give me back a future with the same lifetime". What we use to achieve the effect of "I'm giving you some lifetime, but let me choose which" is called [HRTB](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) (Higher-Kinded Trait Bounds).

If you only wanted to return a specific type, not a generic type, it would look like:

```rust
async fn call_changer<'a, F, Fut>(changer: F)
where
    F: for<'a> FnOnce(&'a mut i32) -> &'a mut i32,
{ ... }
```

You can use `Box<dyn Future>` with this syntax as well:

```rust
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;

async fn call_changer<F>(changer: F)
where
    F: for<'a> FnOnce(&'a mut i32) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + 'a>>,
{
    let mut i = 0;
    changer(&mut i).await;
    dbg!(i);
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    call_changer(|i| {
        Box::pin(async move {
            *i = 100;
        })
    })
    .await;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=7dbc7b6fe091d860452843450638cc75).

In fact, you can even get rid of the explicit `for` clause, since HRTB is the default desugaring for lifetimes in closures:

```rust
where
    F: FnOnce(&mut i32) -> &mut i32,
```

```rust
where
    F: FnOnce(&mut i32) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + '_>>,
```

The only question left is: How do we express this with generic `Fut`?

It's tempting to try to apply the `for<'a>` to multiple conditions:

```rust
where
    for<'a>
        F: FnOnce(&'a mut i32) -> Fut,
        Fut: Future<Output = ()> + 'a,
```

Or:

```rust
where
    for<'a> FnOnce(&'a mut i32) -> (Fut + 'a),
    Fut: Future<Output = ()>,
```

But both doesn't work, unfortunately.

What can we do?

One option is to stay with `Pin<Box<dyn Future>>`.

Another is to use a custom trait:

```rust
trait AsyncSingleArgFnOnce<Arg>: FnOnce(Arg) -> <Self as AsyncSingleArgFnOnce<Arg>>::Fut {
    type Fut: Future<Output = <Self as AsyncSingleArgFnOnce<Arg>>::Output>;
    type Output;
}

impl<Arg, F, Fut> AsyncSingleArgFnOnce<Arg> for F
where
    F: FnOnce(Arg) -> Fut,
    Fut: Future,
{
    type Fut = Fut;
    type Output = Fut::Output;
}

async fn call_changer<F>(changer: F)
where
    F: for<'a> AsyncSingleArgFnOnce<&'a mut i32, Output = ()>,
{
    let mut i = 0;
    changer(&mut i).await;
    dbg!(i);
}
```

Unfortunately, this does not work with closures. I don't know why. You have to put a `fn`:

```rust
#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    async fn callback(i: &mut i32) {
        *i += 100;
    }
    call_changer(callback).await;
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=fdcce5260264e684e948e176f7937650).

For more information:

- [Lifetimes with async function parameters - users.rust-lang.org](https://users.rust-lang.org/t/lifetimes-with-async-function-parameters/51338/) (the trait approach is from there).
- [Generic for FnOnce that returns a future with a lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65316753/generic-for-fnonce-that-returns-a-future-with-a-lifetime).
- [How to talk about lifetime of opaque FnOnce result? - internals.rust-lang.org](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/how-to-talk-about-lifetime-of-opaque-fnonce-result/13783).

Comment: Thanks, the second you mentioned the `'static` I knew where my reasoning went wrong and once again forgot about `for<'a>`, but your answer is extremely detailed and helpful!

Comment: Just as a follow up: I tried to make the trait work for closures by making it less generic implementing `FnOnce(&'a mut Arg)`, with `Arg` being `'static` and I hit [this rust issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/70263). So that seems to be a language limitation for now.