# When I store a async function in a struct, why it need a lifetime

Tags: rust

```
#[derive(Default, Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Eq, Hash, PartialEq)]
pub struct Component {
    name: String,
    module: String,
    r#type: String,
    url: String,
    hash: Option<String>,
    #[serde(skip)]
    retied_times: i8,
}

struct Tasks<'a, F>
where
    F: Future<Output = Result<()>>,
{
    foo: fn(&'a str, &'a Component) -> F,
}

impl<'a, F> Tasks<'a, F>
where
    F: Future<Output = Result<()>>,
{
    pub async fn call(&self, target_dir: &'a str, component: &'a Component) {
        (task)(target_dir, component).await;
    }
}
pub async fn process(target_dir: &str, component: &Component) {
    let task = Tasks { foo: download };
    task.call(target_dir, component);
}

async fn download(target_dir: &str, component: &Component) -> Result<()> {
    //...
}
```

This code will works just fine.

But when I remove the lifetime `'a` in the struct `Tasks`, I won't compile.
The compile error is:

```
 --> src/lib.rs:28:29
   |
28 |     let task = Tasks { foo: download };
   |                             ^^^^^^^^ one type is more general than the other
   |
   = note: expected fn pointer `for<'r, 's> fn(&'r str, &'s component::Component) -> _`
                 found fn item `for<'r, 's> fn(&'r str, &'s component::Component) -> impl Future<Output = Result<(), anyhow::Error>> {download}`
```

Why is this happening?

Comment: Your code is not a Minimal Reproducible Example.

Comment: [Here's more minimal, and working, code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=82fee02b54fe56422bcd1ca52aee4ab1).

Comment: I'm more interested why this works when you specify the lifetime...

Comment: Sorry about my code. I'm a newbee here. I'll provide Minimal Reproducible Example next time. And your answer literaly enlighten me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: If some answer helped you, you should mark it as accepted (click the V near it). And also upvote it if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The future returned by an async function captures all of its lifetime parameters. That is, the following:

```rust
async fn download(target_dir: &str, component: &Component) -> Result<()> {
    // ...
}
```

Is actually a shortcut for the following:

```rust
fn download<'a, 'b>(target_dir: &'a str, component: &'b Component) -> impl Future<Output = Result<()>> + 'a + 'b {
    async move {
        // ...
    }
}
```

That is, the future is parameterized over the lifetimes too.

When you use `'a` in `Tasks`, you instantiate `download` with `'a`. That is, `Tasks { foo: download }` is actually `Tasks { foo: download::<'a, 'a> }` (not valid Rust, but the idea is clear). Its returned future type is also instantiated with `'a`. So you got a concrete type `fn(&'a str, &'a Component)`, and a concrete future type. This is working well.

However, when you leave `'a` outside, your `fn` and `Future` types are still parametric. For the `fn` type, this is not a problem: we can use Higher-Ranked Trait Bounds (`for<'a, 'b> fn(&'a str, &'b Component)`, or with lifetime elision just `fn(&str, &Component)`) to specify that. But with the future type, we cannot express it being parametric (at least, not easily; but see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70592053/7884305)). This is the error you saw: the compiler expected a concrete future type for `F`, but got a parametric ("more general") type for it.