# Async closure holding reference over await point

Tags: rust, async-await, closures

Is there a workaround for creating an async closure that holds a reference over an await point?

### Example:

```rust
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::time::sleep;

fn main() {
    let closure = |v: &u64| async move {
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
        println!("{}", v);
    };
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=26fb4d6630002d6032a7bbffadabcdb9)

Fails with:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:5:29
  |
5 |       let closure = |v: &u64| async move {
  |  _______________________-___-_^
  | |                       |   |
  | |                       |   return type of closure `[async block@src/main.rs:5:29: 8:6]` contains a lifetime `'2`
  | |                       let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
6 | |         sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
7 | |         println!("{}", v);
8 | |     };
  | |_____^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
```

I'm aware that async closures could help. This works:

```rust
#![feature(async_closure)]

use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::time::sleep;

fn main() {
    let closure = async move |v: &u64| {
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
        println!("{}", v);
    };
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=f2430d6fbfc45f658fe10604f0ee22e7)

but given that they're not stable yet, I was wondering if there is any other workaround to make this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the compiler infers the closure to accept `&'some_lifetime u64` instead of `&'any_lifetime u64` as it would do for functions.

Usually, when this is a problem we can pass the closure into a function that takes it and returns it but constrain the closure to be `for<'a> Fn(&'a u64)` (or just `Fn(&u64)`), and this helps the compiler infer the right lifetime. But here we cannot do that, because such function will disallow the returned future to borrow from the parameter, as I explained in [Calling a generic async function with a (mutably) borrowed argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70591386/calling-a-generic-async-function-with-a-mutably-borrowed-argument/).

If you can change the closure to a function, this is the simplest solution.

Otherwise, if the closure captures, you can box the returned future and then use the aforementioned function:

```rust
use std::future::Future;
use std::pin::Pin;

fn force_hrtb<F: Fn(&u64) -> Pin<Box<dyn Future<Output = ()> + '_>>>(f: F) -> F {
    f
}

let closure = force_hrtb(|v: &u64| {
    Box::pin(async move {
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
        println!("{}", v);
    })
});
```

If the cost of boxing and dynamic dispatch is unacceptable, but you can use nightly, you can use the unstable feature [`closure_lifetime_binder`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/3216-closure-lifetime-binder.html) to force the compiler to treate `&u64` as `&'any_lifetime u64`. Unfortunately, because `closure_lifetime_binder` requires the return type to be written explicitly, we also need to do that and we can do that only with another unstable feature, [`type_alias_impl_trait`](https://rust-lang.github.io/rfcs/2515-type_alias_impl_trait.html):

```rust
#![feature(closure_lifetime_binder, type_alias_impl_trait)]
    
use std::future::Future;

type ClosureRet<'a> = impl Future<Output = ()> + 'a;
let closure = for<'a> |v: &'a u64| -> ClosureRet<'a> {
    async move {
        sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
        println!("{}", v);
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that there's no way to indicate that the closure's return includes the reference. Normally you can do this with `impl` syntax, but that's not allowed on closures.

```rs
// not allowed
|v: &'a u64| -> impl Future + 'a
```

So instead, you can make it an async function, which does this automatically.

```rs
fn main() {
    let closure = |v| c(v);
}

async fn c(v: &u64) {
    sleep(Duration::from_secs(1)).await;
    println!("{}", v);
}
```

If you need to capture anything, you can add it to the function arguments.