# How to handle lifetimes in closures combined with closures as params and return types?

Tags: rust, closures, lifetime

I've tried writing a closure that receives a closure (let's call it A) that returns a closure that receives a value and then applies closure A to it.

Sample:

```
let do_some = |f: &dyn Fn(u32) -> u32| move |x: u32| f(x);
let result = do_some(&|v: u32| v * 1111)(7);
```

Observation:

- the reason the closure `f` is a `&dyn Fn()` is because it is the only way the compiler would let me pass a closure to another closure
- the move operator on the innermost closure is to avoid `f` being borrowed by the innermost closure

Problem:

```
error: lifetime may not live long enough
 --> src/main.rs:2:44
  |
2 |     let do_some = |f: &dyn Fn(u32) -> u32| move |x: u32| f(x);
  |                       -                  - ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ returning this value requires that `'1` must outlive `'2`
  |                       |                  |
  |                       |                  return type of closure `[closure@src/main.rs:2:44: 2:57]` contains a lifetime `'2`
  |                       let's call the lifetime of this reference `'1`
```

How to specify lifetime when closures don't allow generic lifetime specification via thee `<'a'>` notation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a quirk of type inference in closures. The compiler thinks the closure accepts `&'a dyn Fn` with some specific lifetime `'a`, but you actually want it to take `&'a dyn Fn` for *any* lifetime `'a` (HRTB). This fact causes it to error for reasons I won't explain here (because they're long and complicated).

On nightly, it is possible to "fix" the wrong lifetime as follows (yep, this is cumbersome):

```rust
#![feature(closure_lifetime_binder, type_alias_impl_trait)]

type RetFn<'a> = impl Fn(u32) -> u32 + 'a;
let do_some = for<'a> |f: &'a dyn Fn(u32) -> u32| -> RetFn<'a> { move |x: u32| f(x) };
```

On stable, unfortunately, as far as I know there is no way to fix this error. But you can avoid the problem in the first place by using a `Box` instead of a reference:

```rust
let do_some = |f: Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> u32>| move |x: u32| f(x);
let result = do_some(Box::new(|v: u32| v * 1111))(7);
```

Alternatively, you can box the *returned* closure, and use a little helper function to help the compiler figure the right lifetime:

```rust
fn force_hrtb<F: Fn(&dyn Fn(u32) -> u32) -> Box<dyn Fn(u32) -> u32 + '_>>(f: F) -> F {
    f
}
let do_some = force_hrtb(|f| Box::new(move |x: u32| f(x)));
let result = do_some(&|v: u32| v * 1111)(7);
```

[I explained a bit more about the problem here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76626195/7884305).