# Pattern for statefully processing async data in Rust

Tags: asynchronous, rust, rust-tokio

Consider the following complete example in Rust:

```
use async_stream::stream;
use futures::{pin_mut, StreamExt};
use std::time::Duration;
use tokio::time::sleep;

pub struct Processor {
    pub state: i32,
}

impl Processor {
    pub fn process(&mut self, x: i32) -> i32 {
        self.state += 1;
        self.state * x
    }
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let mut p = Processor { state: 1 };

    let stream = stream! {
        for i in 1..=10 {
            sleep(Duration::from_millis(100)).await;
            yield i
        }
    };

    let s2 = stream.filter_map(move |m| async {
        match m {
            7 => None,
            _ => Some(p.process(m)),
        }
    });
    pin_mut!(s2);

    while let Some(v) = s2.next().await {
        println!("Next value {:?}", v);
    }
}
```

This design very simply has a stateful processing adapter that receives items, changes state, and returns some value.

However, this example does not compile due to:

```
error: captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body
  --> src/main.rs:28:41
   |
19 |       let mut p = Processor { state: 1 };
   |           ----- variable defined here
...
28 |       let s2 = stream.filter_map(move |m| async {
   |  _______________________________________-_^
   | |                                       |
   | |                                       inferred to be a `FnMut` closure
29 | |         match m {
30 | |             7 => None,
31 | |             _ => Some(p.process(m)),
   | |                       - variable captured here
32 | |         }
33 | |     });
   | |_____^ returns an `async` block that contains a reference to a captured variable, which then escapes the closure body
```

The problem is that on one hand, we have an adapter that holds state, and on the other hand an async part of the program (`filter_map` in this case) that requires to hold a mutable reference to that adapter.

What is the proper design to implement such an async loop? In certain cases it can be possible to split away the async part e.g. first apply a synchronous `map` and then chain the async `filter_map` to it, but my question is for the more general case where an async block *must* hold some mutable reference.

Another cop-out in this case would be to clone the processor, but for the sake of discussion let's assume that would be bad for performance.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand you correctly: even though in this case the manipulation is not really async, in your real use case it is?

Comment: @ChayimFriedman - yes, exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`StreamExt::filter_map()` (and similar methods) cannot support that, they were not designed for this ([issue #2464](https://github.com/rust-lang/futures-rs/issues/2464)), and I don't think they can be redesigned to handle this.

You can create your own stream combinator to do that, but even this is not that simple. It is impossible (AFAIK) currently to have a signature that accepts all async blocks that borrow from their parameter. See [Calling a generic async function with a (mutably) borrowed argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70591386/calling-a-generic-async-function-with-a-mutably-borrowed-argument) for details. A possible partial solution is to box the returned future and return `Pin<Box<dyn Future>>` (at the cost of a memory allocation), or use trait magic for that, but this only works with async functions, not closures that return async blocks (at least, not without weird signatures and unstable features like [`type_alias_impl_trait`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/63063) and [`closure_lifetime_binder`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/97362)).