# Function as trait with output type polymorphic in lifetime

Tags: rust, polymorphism, lifetime, higher-kinded-types, quantified-constraints

How do I express a constraint like

```
fn<F: 'static> apply_to_foos(f: F)
where
for<'a> F: fn(&'a mut Foo) -> impl Future<Output = Bar> + 'a
{
...
}
```

(The above expression doesn't work because constraints can't have `impl` in them)

If this isn't possible, what can I do instead?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Generic for FnOnce that returns a future with a lifetime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65316753/generic-for-fnonce-that-returns-a-future-with-a-lifetime)

Comment: Also [Calling a generic async function with a (mutably) borrowed argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70591386/calling-a-generic-async-function-with-a-mutably-borrowed-argument/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a heap allocated trait object we already can express that constraint with current compiler featuers (Rust 1.61).

```rust
fn apply_to_foos<F>(f: F)
where
    for<'a> F: Fn(&'a mut Foo) -> Box<dyn Future<Output = Bar> + 'a>
{ /*...*/ }
```

Maybe this is already what we want to do, but for fun and games, let's say we want to use compile time polymorphy:

It is concievable that a future version of Rust would just allow us to replace the `dyn` in the above signature and replace it with an `impl`, while dropping the `Box` altogether. FYI: The `Box` is not needed for above signature to compile, but most real world usecase would require it in order to keep the trait object alive long enough.

Using an `impl` here would require the compiler to support `trait`s which can in turn depend on other `traits`. Rust cannot do that, but `trait`s can depend on concrete types. Let's introduce a type `O` into our signature.

```rust
fn apply_to_foos<F, O>(f: F)
where
    for<'a> F: Fn(&'a mut Foo) -> O, O: Future<Output = Bar>
{ /*...*/ }
```

This almost does what we want, but we have no way to transfer the lifetime requirement of `'a` to `O`, since `&'a` is local to the constraint of `F`. We can factor out the entire constraint into its own trait however:

```rust
fn apply_to_foos<F, O>(f: F) where F: for<'a> FooToBar<'a> {}
```

with `FooToBar` being declared like this (for example):

```
trait FooToBar<'a> {
    type O: Future<Output = Bar> + 'a;

    fn foo_to_bar(&self, foo: &'a mut Foo) -> Self::O;
}
```

Wether avoiding the heap allocation is worth the code bloat likely depends on your domain. I'd probably stick with the `Box<dyn>` version most of the time.